# diesel mysql how to set time_zone

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I am using diesel 1.4.8, with mysql database, I want to set `SET time_zone = '+8:00';` for each link, but diesel sets default config after each connection, but these config Not what I want, how can I modify the default configuration of diesel settings.

This is the code I found in diesel source code `diesel/src/mysql/connection/mod.rs`

```rs
    fn establish(database_url: &str) -> ConnectionResult<Self> {
        use result::ConnectionError::CouldntSetupConfiguration;

        let raw_connection = RawConnection::new();
        let connection_options = ConnectionOptions::parse(database_url)?;
        raw_connection.connect(&connection_options)?;
        let conn = MysqlConnection {
            raw_connection: raw_connection,
            transaction_manager: AnsiTransactionManager::new(),
            statement_cache: StatementCache::new(),
        };


        conn.set_config_options().map_err(CouldntSetupConfiguration)?;

        Ok(conn)
    }

...

    fn set_config_options(&self) -> QueryResult<()> {
        self.execute("SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',PIPES_AS_CONCAT'))")?;
        self.execute("SET time_zone = '+00:00';")?;
        self.execute("SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4'")?;
        self.execute("SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4'")?;
        self.execute("SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4'")?;
        Ok(())
    }
```

What I want now is `self.execute("SET time_zone = '+8:00';")?;` instead of the default `self.execute("SET time_zone = '+00:00';")? ;`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change dependency code without forking the dependency. So changing literally this line is only possible if you maintain a forked diesel version for yourself. That written: Nothing stops you to just literally execute `conn.execute("SET time_zone = '+8:00';")` with any created connection. This resets the default setup.
Please note that this likely breaks any timezone related functionality in diesel, as this ("time_zone = '+00:00'") is a fundamental assumption of that code.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution

Use a macro to modify the timezone before each use of the link

```rs
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! conn {
    ( $x:expr ) => {{
        let conn = $x.get()?;
        conn.execute("SET time_zone = '+8:00';")?;
        conn
    }};
}
```

Used when calling the api interface

```rs
pub async fn create(pool: web::Data<DbPool>, form: HttpBody<mods::book::BookNew>) -> HttpResult {
    use schema::*;
    let form = form.into_inner();
    form.validate().map_err(|e| ErrorBadRequest(json!(e)))?;

    let res = web::block(move || -> Result<usize, DbError> {
        // let conn = pool.get()?;
        let conn = conn!(pool);
        Ok(diesel::insert_into(books::table)
            .values(&form)
            .execute(&conn)?)
    })
    .await?
    .map_err(ErrorInternalServerError)?;

    Ok(HttpResponse::Ok().json(res))
}
```

---

The first data use `let conn = pool.get()?;`, the second data use `let conn = conn!(pool);` works fine

[image]